# JavaScript - Move caret to next line (simulate down arrow click) in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have got problem. I am trying to make a function which moves caret to the line which is below in contenteditable div and I have no idea how to do that. Let me explain my problem:

```js
function SomeMagicFunction() {

}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="SomeMagicFunction();">Move to next line</button>
<div contenteditable="true" id="box">
  <p>SomeTextSomeText</p>
  <p>SomeTextSomeText</p>
  <p>SomeTextSomeText</p>
  <p>SomeTextSomeText</p>
  <p>SomeTextSomeText</p>
  <p>SomeTextSomeText</p>
  <p>SomeTextSomeText</p>
  <p>SomeTextSomeText</p>
</div>
```

In the above example, after placing the cursor/caret in the first line and pressing the button, the cursor/caret should be in the second line. I don't know how to make this `MagicFunction()`. So how to do that using JavaScript and/or JQuery? Thanks for help.